# Reading xml comment outside the tag

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

i have some problem with deserialization  some of xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Group>
  <GroupName>.NET</GroupName>2345
 </Group>
 <!-- ID: [123] -->
```

How can i get comment(need to get ID) from this xml.

Implement IXmlSerializer it's would be so huge. any ideas how to do in a different way?

if this comment could be between tag - it's not be a problem use XmlAttributeOverrides but it's not.

This is start of processes:

```
    public object XmlFromStream(HttpWebResponse resp, Type type)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer;
        StreamReader responseStream = null;
        try
        {
            xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
            Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            responseStream = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), enc);
            object objectFromXml = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(responseStream);
            return objectFromXml;
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            throw Ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (responseStream != null) responseStream.Close();
        }
    }
```

please show what is next.

ThanX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The document has only a single root/document element, but it also has other nodes. Using Linq2Xml, you can fish it out like this:

```
 var doc = XDocument.Parse(docStr);
 var commentValue = doc.Nodes().OfType<XComment>().First().Value;
```

Comment: How about full example.

Comment: @AleksP : A reminder of your question: "How can i get comment". I've gone beyond that by providing the *value* of the comment. Isn't this a full example? If you have your document in a string call `docStr`, then what else could you possibly need? I'm not going to provide a compilable solution file for you. If you need more info, perhaps it might serve you better to ask a better question...